# Why Delphi XE3 gives "E2382 Cannot call constructors using instance variables"?

Tags: delphi, object, constructor

I have a simple piece of code, that compiles in Delphi XE2 but not in XE3, and I don't know why. I have reduced the problematic code to a small bit and would like to know what's wrong with it in Delphi's opinion. Trying to compile a project containing this unit in Delphi XE 2 works fine, but in Delphi XE3 (trial), it gives "[dcc32 Error] AffineTransform.pas(26): E2382 Cannot call constructors using instance variables". The only "eccentric" thing I know of here is the use of the old-school "object" type, where the constructor isn't really exactly the same thing as in real objects (TObject-based class instances).

If I replace the words 'constructor' in this object with 'procedure', then it compiles ok, but why is this, and is this an ok change to do in my code, i.e. is it a change that will have no effect on the functionality?

```
unit AffineTransform;

interface

type
  { Rectangular area. }
  TCoordRect = object
  public
    Left, Top, Right, Bottom: Real;
    constructor CreatePos(ALeft, ATop, ARight, ABottom: Real);
    procedure   Include(AX, AY: Real);
  end;

implementation

constructor TCoordRect.CreatePos(ALeft, ATop, ARight, ABottom: Real);
begin
  Left := ALeft;
  Top := ATop;
  Right := ARight;
  Bottom := ABottom;
end;

procedure TCoordRect.Include(AX, AY: Real);
begin
  CreatePos(AX, AY, AX, AY)
end;

end.
```

Comment: Why are you implementing constructors on legacy Turbo Pascal objects? That should be a procedure, and it should be called `Initialize`.

Comment: @LaKraven There is no inherited Create. This is `object` and not `class`.

Comment: Didn't spot that, @DavidHeffernan. Cheers!

Comment: This is not originally my code, just something that has fallen into my hands, so I can't say the original motivations of the author. As far as I know the intent of the Create and CreatePos methods is just to initialize the structure, so I'd guess that calling them constructor is just an idea to make them visually stand out from the code as initialization methods. But since I'm not sure, that's basically what I'm asking here, i.e. is there any functional difference between 'constructor' and 'procedure' here, why I should not just change the term? Also, curiosity, why XE3 gives error and XE2not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this legacy Turbo Pascal style `object`, there is really no meaning to the keyword `constructor`. Although an `object` constructor does have some special treatment, there's absolutely no need for that here. What have here is nothing more than a `record` with some methods.

The XE3 compiler was changed so that it no longer allows you to call a constructor on `Self` inside an instance method. That is the case for both `class` and `object`. I've not seen any documentation of why this change was made. No doubt in time it will seep out.

Your immediate solution is to replace `constructor` with `procedure`. In the longer term, it would make sense to turn this into a `record` rather than an `object`.

---

I would also council you to change the name of the method to `Initialize`. Some library designers seem to opt for using `Create` and `Free` methods on their records. This had led to immense amount of code being written like this:

```
ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
try
  ....
finally
  ctx.Free;
end;
```

In fact all that code is spurious and can simply be removed! A `TRttiContext` variable will automatically initialize itself.

That sort of design also sets a giant [Heffalump Trap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heffalump) for that faction of Delphi coders that like to use `FreeAndNil`. Passing a record to `FreeAndNil` leads to some interesting fireworks!

Comment: So how does this play out when you have multiple constructors - with different names - and want to call one from inside the other. I do hope that is still allowed? Should be, after all they are all constructors, so class methods and not instance methods...

Comment: @marjan Yeah, that's allowed.

Comment: +1 for "Heffalump Trap".  I am now eagerly looking forward to working that into a report somehow... :)

Comment: Thanks for the good answer! You left me with some final small doubts with this comment: "Although an object constructor does have some special treatment, there's absolutely no need for that here." Because what I've shown here is a reduced version of the original code, just to reproduce the error, so I'm wondering what this "some special treatment" might be, in case it would still somehow have some relevance regarding the original code of mine.

Comment: The special treatment is a call to `_ObjSetup` in System.pas that sets up the VMT pointer in the object. Since your object is nothing more than a plain old record, and doesn't have any virtual methods, that doesn't apply here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My actual objects have several methods and some of them are overloads of one another, but none of them is virtual, so if that is the key, then I believe I'm indeed in the clear.

Comment: In that case convert `object` to `record`. There's no place for `object` these days.

Answer (score 6):

> I have a simple piece of code, that compiles in Delphi XE2 but not in XE3, and I don't know why.

You are trying to call a constructor inside of a method of an instance that is already instantiated and initialiized.  The compiler does not allow that anymore.  More specifically, this code:

```
procedure TCoordRect.Include(AX, AY: Real); 
begin 
  CreatePos(AX, AY, AX, AY) 
end;
```

Is the same as this code:

```
procedure TCoordRect.Include(AX, AY: Real); 
begin 
  Self.CreatePos(AX, AY, AX, AY) 
end;
```

And you cannot call a constructor on the `Self` variable anymore.  Why?  IIRC, it has to do with compiler's ongoing shift to supporting mobile development.

Comment: +1 for the comment on "it has to do with compiler's ongoing shift to supporting mobile development." which is the best info I've got about the reasons. Of course it would be nice to have even better info, also the Delphi documentation has no content on this error message, so that would be nice too. But thanks for giving even this! :)

Comment: I think Remy's alluding to the next gen compiler that is being developed. Emba are mopping up some of the oddities in the current compiler and trying to align the legacy compiler with next gen as much as is reasonable.