# Delphi XE4 gives E2036 when accessing generic list items of 'object's

Tags: delphi, object, compiler-errors, delphi-xe4

This is probably similar / continuation on the previous question below:

[Why Delphi XE3 gives "E2382 Cannot call constructors using instance variables"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953393/why-delphi-xe3-gives-e2382-cannot-call-constructors-using-instance-variables)

Now I'm trying Delphi XE4 with the same code (with 'constructor' changed to 'procedure' as per the solution of the above question).

Now I have also these things in a generics list, i.e. I have

```
TCoordRect = object
public
  function Something: Boolean;
end;
```

and then a list of these in a function parameter, which I loop through and try to access the items directly:

```
function DoSomething(AList: TList<TCoordRect>): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for i := 0 to AList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Result := Result or AList[i].Something;  // <-- Here comes the compiler error!
  end;
end;
```

This gives the compiler error "E2036 Variable required". However, if I don't access it directly, i.e put instead a local variable and use that first, then it works:

```
function DoSomething(AList: TList<TCoordRect>): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
  ListItem: TCoordRect;
begin
  Result := False;
  for i := 0 to AList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    ListItem := AList[i];
    Result := Result or ListItem.Something;  // <-- Now this compiles!
  end;
end;
```

And another "workaround" is to remove all these 'object' types and change them to 'class', but I'm curious as to why this does not work like it used to? Is it again just something with "the compiler moving towards mobile development" or is there some more specific reason, or is this even a bug? BTW I also reported this as a QC issue, so will see if something comes from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a compiler bug, and it's present in all earlier versions of the compiler. The fault is not limited to XE4. Submitting a QC report is the correct response.

I would not be surprised if Embarcadero never attempt to fix it. That's because you are using deprecated `object`. Switch to using `record` and the code compiles.

The issue you have uncovered in this question is unrelated to the SO question you refer to at the top of your question.

Incidentally, this really is a case of old meets new. Legacy Turbo Pascal objects, and modern day generic containers. You are mixing oil and water!

Comment: I'm unsure if reinstated `object` type in Delphi is really a **legacy**.

Comment: Regarding the 'all earlier versions' - the same code compiles without errors on XE3 and XE2. I also would not be surprised if they are not fixing this, and I agree this is a case of old meets new and sort of begging for problems :). The relation to the other question is mainly due to the fact that it is based on the same code, so well, I guess it depends on what you define as a relation, to me it is related. P.S. If I get from anywhere a more inside answer than "compiler bug" then I'll accept that, otherwise I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @DelphiUser Not for me. The code fails in the exact same way 2010, XE2, XE3 and XE4. It's not related in the sense that the other question concerns constructors on `object`, and this question concerns a generics compiler bug.

Comment: @user539484 http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Classes_and_Objects#Object_Types  "Object types are supported for backward compatibility only. Their use is not recommended on Win32."  I'd regard that as legacy.

Comment: A mix of oil and water (or any two usually non-miscable fluids) is called an emulsion. ;-)

Comment: @David: fully agreed. That means they are deprecated and should indeed not be used in Win32 anymore. They were kept in Delphi to keep code compatible with 16 bit code for Windows.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In this case we don't have an emulsion because we don't have an emulsifier - we need some mustard!!  ;-)

Comment: One can also create emulsions by simply mixing very hard.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I guess that's something you do in your line of work!